# Как достать текст из EditText?

Tags: java, android

Я сделал `DialogFragment` со своим `layout` вот так установил

```
 AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);
```

Так вот в этом `layout` который установлен в `DialogFragment` есть `EditText`.
Суть в том, что когда появляется `DialogFragment` юзер должен ввести в `EditText` свой комментарий и нажать на кнопку отправить.

Была проблема с тем, что я не мог выполнить `findViewById()` так как `DialogFragment` не наследует от `Activity`, но я вроде как решил эту проблему таким способом

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_note_dialog, null);
EditText etNoteFromWeb = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);
String response = etNoteFromWeb.getText().toString();
```

И вроде нет ни ошибок и все ок, но при таком подходе всегда мне возвращается `""` не `null` а именно пустая строчка...

Подскажите как достать текст из `EditText`.

**Что я делаю не так?**

Вот полный код класса

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

final String LOG_TAG = "MyDialog";
private static MyDialog myDialog;
private EditText etNoteFromWeb;

int layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    layout = args.getInt("layout");
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

    if (layout == R.layout.activity_note_dialog) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        LinearLayout llSent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSent);
        LinearLayout llSkip = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSkip);

        llSent.setOnClickListener(listener);
        llSkip.setOnClickListener(listener);
        adb.setView(view);
    }

    return adb.create();
}

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (layout == R.layout.activity_note_dialog) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_note_dialog, null);
            etNoteFromWeb = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);
            String response = etNoteFromWeb.getText().toString();
//                String response = "etNoteFromWeb.getText().toString()";
            // Здесь в System.out.println ничего нет...9(( но когда раскоментирована строка 
            // выше и указываю статический текст, то все работает, проблема именно в том, 
            // что не достает текст из EditText
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + response);
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.llSent:
                    onClick.onDialogClickListener(response);
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                case R.id.llSkip:
                    onClick.onDialogClickListener(null);
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

public void dismissDialog(final MyDialog dialog, int daleyTime) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, daleyTime);
}

public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onDismiss");
}

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onCancel");
}

public static MyDialog newInstance(int layout) {
    myDialog = new MyDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    myDialog.setArguments(args);

    return myDialog;
}


//  Этот интерфейс я реализовал для того чтоб можно было передавать данные из DialogFragment
public interface OnButtonClick {
    void onDialogClickListener(String response);
}

OnButtonClick onClick;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        onClick = (OnButtonClick) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onDialogClickListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    onClick = null;
}
}
```

Comment: Это два разных editText-a, один в диалоге другой в view.

Comment: @nekaneka Что вы имеете ввиду? И как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2):

На уровне класса объявите переменную:

```
EditText et;
```

Инициализируйте её при создании диалога, но до его показа:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

Dialog d = builder.build();
et = d.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);
```

Теперь вы можете к ней образаться из других методов пока диалог существует.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос кодом, мне кажется ваш ответ все же мне не поможет так как я пытаюсь взять EditText из лисенера... Диалог а тому моменту уже наверняка создан

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, вынесите EditText et в переменную класса и всё заработает.

Comment: Обновил код, `EditText` вынес вверх как глобальную переменную, но ничего не поменялось...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, вы не тот EditText юзаете. Инфлейтер загружает разметку но она не является той, кою вы  диалоге используете. При создании диалога инициализируйте едит как у меня в ответе. В лушателе не нужнен вам инфлейтер.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но я наверное опять вас не так понял)) Я значит делаю так, у меня в коде из вопроса в методе `onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)` сначала идут первые 3 строчки инициализации, потом я пишу 2 строчки из вашего ответа `Dialog d = builder.build();
et = d.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);`
Но у меня подчеркивает красным `builder.build();` я так понял, что может вы ошиблись и поменял на `adb.create();` согласно моего кода... Но все равно не работает... Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Все разобрался, ответ написал... Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

В итоге как я понял суть была в том, что я создавал новый обьект `layout` и пытался с его `EditText` получить строку. Нужно было обьявить `EditText` как глобальную переменную и инициализировать ее здесь вот так :

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

    if (layout == R.layout.activity_note_dialog) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        ------->  etNoteFromWeb = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNoteFromWeb);


        LinearLayout llSent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSent);
        LinearLayout llSkip = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSkip);

        llSent.setOnClickListener(listener);
        llSkip.setOnClickListener(listener);
        adb.setView(view);
    }

    return adb.create();
}
```

И все заработало